# spring integration channel exception while sending the message to channel from Service activator

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to send the message from my service activator to a direct channel but when my code is trying to execute the `channel.send(<MSG>)` method it is giving the **error**: `09:51:08.436 [durableExecutor-1] ERROR c.c.g.d.s.InboundMetaDataReport - ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.`

I have ran the same code in some other project but here not able to figure out that why it is not working. Please help.

Below is the **full stack trace**:

```
09:51:25.355 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel$send.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at com.cigna.group.dna.service.InboundMetaDataReport.processDurableMessage(InboundMetaDataReport.groovy:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:94)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:64)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:271)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75)
```

Comment: Spring integration COnfig:  <int:channel id="inputChannel"/> and in the service activator I have @Autowired
 @Qualifier("inputChannel")
 MessageChannel inputChannel; and calling the send method with inputChannel.send(xmlDomMessage).

Comment: You should share the config and code of your service. Looks like message can't reach exactly your service. Not a problem of this your send.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got the reason for this issue. when I am sending this message to the channel, it is going but there is another service acitivator which is the subscriber for this channel and that service activator is having 5 methods with the same name and different parameters. I am sending Message<Document> type message but none of these method is having this type of parameter. So I am writing a new method with parameter type Message<Document> and that should work fine.

Comment: OK. Sounds like an answer! You can answer to your own question to share your experience and let other people to know how to overcome similar issues.